Trying to identify an anime that aired in the UK late 90's. Kinda Isekai, very Ecchi
So I'm trying to identify an Anime that I'm pretty sure I saw a bit of in the late 90s on UK TV, probably late at night.
These teens got sucked into a fantasy game through their computer, possibly VR or they got pulled in by a virus. I distinctly remember the game or virus coming on a floppy disk, which I thought was amusing given CD media was a thing.
The art style was Pokemon-esque, which made it even more incongruous when protag lad has sex in the game, straight off the bat, in the middle of the overworld field by a random female, or possibly not random cos part of me remembers thinking "wait, wasn't she supposed to be his sister. Even if it's in a video game that's not right".

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TrappedInAnotherWorld/AnimeAndManga

Or https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InsideAComputerSystem

Also maybe https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/trapped-in-a-video-game

Any ideas if this was dubbed or subbed? And what channel it might have been on? There were some "sucked into a videogame" anime from the 90s (such as NG Knight Ramune & 40), but they weren't all that common before 2002's .hack//SIGN and 2012's Sword Art Online.

I think Subbed, badly. I want to say it was Channel 4 but it might have been on a satellite channel - definitely a late night one. NG Knight looks like a hoot, but I don't recall this being quite so frenetic as that.
